# Como criar um Trigger pra uma coluna especifica de uma tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Criei um **trigger** pra minha tabela **X**, com o proposito de fazer um registro de **update** que o correm nessa tabela.

Pra cada **update** na tabela **X**, os valores modificados (antigos) sao armazenados na tabela **Z**.

**PROBLEMATICA** :

A tabela **X** possui varias colunas, e pra cada **update** numa das colunas o **trigger** é logo disparado.

Sera que é possivel especificar uma **coluna** da tabela **X** pra qual o **trigger** deve ser disparado em caso de uma **update** ?

**LOGICA** :

**Tabela X**

- Si **update** na coluna **y** : dispara o **trigger**
- Si nao ( si for numa outra **coluna**) : nao faça nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No MySql você não pode diretamente disparar uma trigger somente após a alteração de uma coluna. As triggers são disparadas após uma interação (insert, update ou delete) na linha da tabela.
Para o seu caso é necessário filtrar, dentro da trigger, se a coluna sofreu alteração, para só de depois executar a ação desejada (gravação de log no seu caso):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tstTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON Tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if NEW.campo <=> OLD.campo THEN
    --Executa operação
END IF;
END;
```

Ao efetuar um update na linha da tabela a trigger será acionada e vai verificar se o valor da coluna *campo* sofreu alteração. Caso seja diferente, irá executar uma ação, que pode ser a gravação de log.

**Update**
O Postgre permite a restrição de execução de trigger por coluna, conforme documentação:

[Postgresql - Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html)