# Como fazer registros de modificacoes numa Tabela MySQL (sem utilizar triggers )?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Gostaria de saber si existe uma outra tecnica de fazer registros de modificacoes nas tabelas sem passar por **triggers** ?

Comment: Existem formas de fazer via sincronização entre bases de dados. No entanto, com gravação em tabelas no mesmo banco de dados eu desconheço outra forma. Em tempo, como ficou a questão http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172540/como-criar-um-trigger-pra-uma-coluna-especifica-de-uma-tabela?

Comment: @E.Thomas a questão não foi solucionada, razão  pela qual pretendo migrar pra uma outra tecnica !

Comment: @E.Thomas fiquei desapontado ao ver que a pergunta teve uma notação  negativa.. Nao pude perceber a razão  !

Comment: Também não entendi o motivo. Gostaria de saber se minha resposta foi satisfatória, e caso tenha sido, se você pode marca-la como tal.

Comment: @E.Thomas a sua resposta foi suficientemente satisfatoria, farei mais algumas pesquisas a respeito... Valeu !

Comment: quer registrar log do que foi modificado?

Comment: @DanielOmine pretendo registrar os dados que foram modificados ( dados antigo)

Comment: @AndréPKA modificação direta na base ou via alguma linguagem de programação?

Comment: @LucasTorres com uma lingua ou direitamente, as duas formas sao validas pra o meu caso !

Comment: Seria o caso de implementar o audit ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/audit-log.html

Answer (score 0):

André, bom dia

Caso seja via alguma linguagem, como PHP por exemplo, você pode criar um log por exemplo:

```
<?php


function gravaLog($text){

$data = date("d-m-y");
$hora = date("H:i:s");

$arquivo = $data.".txt";     

$texto = "[$hora] - $msg \n";

$arr = fopen("$arquivo", "a+b");
fwrite($aar, $texto);
fclose($aar);

}

?>
```

Então a cada função que manipule o banco você chamaria, exemplo:

```
function insereBanco($reg){
     //sua funcao
     gravaLog("O registro " . $reg . " foi inserido no banco")
}

function alteraBanco($reg){
     //sua funcao
     gravaLog("O registro " . $reg . " foi alterado no banco")
}
function deletaBanco($reg){
     //sua funcao
     gravaLog("O registro " . $reg . " foi excluido no banco")
}
```

Comment: Noto que a funcao gravaLog() esta sendo chamado depois de uma outra funcao : Imagine que trata-se de uma funcao que faz uma **update** na tabela **y**. Como a funcao iria gravar os dados que foram modificados ?

Comment: Essas outras funções foram apenas pra simular o seu processo. Você pode usar ela em qualquer parte do seu código @AndréPKA

Comment: Esta bem... Mas ela guardar o dado antes de ser modificado ?