# Usar ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ao alterar campo específico

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger, default

#### Cenário exemplo

Tabela: `usuarios`

Campos: `id`, `nome`, `sobrenome`, `senha`, `timestamp_alteracao`

---

#### Questão

O campo `timestamp_alteração`, somente deverá ser atualizado quando o campo `senha` for alterado.

---

#### Dúvida

- Existe uma forma de utilizar como valor *default* do campo, para que ele faça essa atualização conforme condição?

  - Caso não, teria que fazer por *update* ou até mesmo por *trigger*?
  - Quais outras opções?

Comment: da para fazer o trigger after update, minha recomendacao seria fazer isso no backend.

Comment: @HudsonPH Não existe forma de usar expressão default então?

Comment: Seria uma duplicata disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172551/112052 ?

Comment: @hkotsubo Não, pois gostaria por expressão default. Trigger seria caso não exista a opção.

Comment: mas o DEFAULT GETDATE() seria para insert e nao update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe uma forma de utilizar como valor *default* do campo, para que ele faça essa atualização conforme condição?

Não em todos os bancos de dados que eu conheço, embora tecnicamente seria possível, mas provavelmente seria extensão ao SQL padrão. O MySQL não permite.

> Caso não, teria que fazer por *update* ou até mesmo por *trigger*?

Por `update` você pode fazer o que quiser, mas não parece ser o que deseja, até porque condicional não poderia ser usado sozinho, e não é garantido.

Gatilhos foram criados justamente para este cenário, toda vez que uma alteração em específico é feita uma ação deve ser feita obrigatoriamente, ou seja, uma ação dispara outra sob controle do próprio SGDB.

Obviamente que este cenário exige um condicional e o gatilho precisa ser poderoso o suficiente para suportar este tipo de coisa, então é provável que seja exigido algo a mais que puro SQL, provavelmente precisa de uma linguagem de programação, ainda que baseada em SQL. MySQL tem `IF`.

> Quais outras opções?

Fazer na aplicação, que tem lá suas vantagens, mas também desvantagens, especialmente se não souber fazer corretamente, não é garantido, a aplicação precisa estar correta (o que pra mim não é problema se a pessoa sabe o que está fazendo, aí depende da pessoa ter um viés de Dev ou DBA).